# Why is zero-weight brush painting with high values?

Tags: weight-painting

I suppose it's strange question, but my brush in weight paint mode is painting with high values. For example, all weights in this screenshot I've got with zero weight (you can see it at the top):
[image]

I've tried multiply and mix blend modes with the same result.
Additionaly, on the left side of jacket there is a little weightened island - I don't know why but I can't weight paint around it (maybe it's related to question). And this problem happened after I've clicked something on keyboard, so, maybe, I caused a problem by myself and I don't know how to fix it.

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: hello could you please share the file (the jacket only)?

Comment: Hey @moonboots! I've added it to question.

Comment: @moonboots I've seen you've added answer and your solution is working. I wonder why have you deleted it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are painting with autonormalize on, on vertices without any weights.

What autonormalize does is tell Blender that you want to keep the sum of all weights on any vertices you paint equal to 1.

When you use a weight 0 multiply brush on these vertices with autonormalize on, here's what Blender understands to do.

1. Assign any vertices that are not yet assigned to this group at 0.
2. Multiply the weight of the affected vertex by the brush weight (0), then mix between this and the starting weight of the vertex (which is also 0) by a factor that is the product of the brush strength (1.0) and the falloff (depends on distance to stroke)-- some other factors can go into that with different tool settings, but it doesn't matter, you're only ever mixing between 0 and 0, your output so far is still 0.
3. After we do this, clamp our generated weights to the 0,1 range.  Again, still 0.
4. Finally, because you have autonormalize on, recalculate weights of all groups such that their sum is 1.  Keeping this group constant if we can, but the ultimate goal is, sum of 1.  Because this group is the only group to which that vertex is assigned, the only way to do this is to set this weight to 1.

It just doesn't make a lot of sense to use autonormalize weight painting on vertices that have not yet been assigned to any vertex groups.  Anything you do to a vertex with one group, with autonormalization, can only ever result in a weight of 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to weight paint on this area you need to increase the *Weight* and choose *Blend > Mix*. Note that the *Auto Normalize* option will substract the weight from the vertices if they are part of other vertex groups.

If you keep the *Auto Normalize* option, if the *Weight* is at 0 and you use *Blend > Multiply* it won't give any weight to the vertices that are not assigned to any other vertex group, which seems logical as 0 x 0 = 0, but I'm not sure why it assigns a *Weight* of 1 to the the vertices that are not assigned yet...

Comment: But why is it breaking everything? It worked fine previously and I've seen people using it  in tutorials because... well, they haven't explained this, but say that in another case - all weights will break.